# Java tcp port connect with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, tcp

How can I connect eclipse to a tcp port that I have point my java programs to?  This is a process that usually runs as a java jar, but I would like to test it in eclipse.  I don't understand how to connect to the port that is set up in my C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\services.

Can I run this through eclipse using this as the tcp port it runs on?  I'm new to socket programming.

Comment: Why do you want "eclipse" to connect? Isn't the Java program that is supposed to connect via a socket? Think on that lines. Ignore the IDE aspects for a while, think in Java programming lines.

Answer (score 1):

**Just run the program.**

The program will still connect to the appropriate port, even if you run it in eclipse.  If you need to specify the port in the command line, then modify the run configuration to specify the port.  If the server is also a java application, then you should run that in eclipse first, and then run your client to connect to it.